# Create a typed array w/ N items in it using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring

I have a method that I'm using to create an array w/ `n` of a specific type of object in it:

```
func many(count: Int) -> [Cube] {
  var cubes: [Cube] = []
  for i in 0...count {
    let cube = CubeFactory.single()
    cubes.append(cube)
  }
  return cubes
}
```

This works but I'm sure there's a more swift like way to do this. Any one know how this can be refactored?

Comment: `func many(count: Int) -> [Cube] { return [Cube](count: count, repeatedValue: Cube.single()) }`

Comment: This is marked as a duplicate, but the referenced question refers to initializing an array with identical values, this question is about initializing it with different values.

Comment: Although at some point it changed so that it probably is initializing it with a single value now.  Need some clarification from the OP about which is actually desired.

Comment: @David Fair enough. I'll reopen in the mean time.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify but they need to be different objects, just of the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `CubeFactory.single()` actually do anything other than return the same instance every time?

If it does active stuff, `return map(0..<count) { _ in CubeFactory.single() }` (or numerous variants) will give you an array of them.

(the `_ in` really oughtn’t to be necessary, but Swift’s type inference gets a bit flummoxed without it and you’ll get an error about half-open intervals – the other possibility for the overloaded `..<` operator – not conforming to SequenceType)

If it’s just inert and every cube is identical, `return Array(count: count, repeatedValue: Cube.single())` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Do you happen to know if the `_ in` thing is going to be addressed at some point?

Comment: no idea but you’ve reminded me I haven’t filed a radar for it :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2, this is

```
let array = (0..<30).map { _ in CubeFactory.single() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but you can use:

```
let array = map(0..<30) { _ in CubeFactory.single() }
```

Comment: You shouldn’t need that `SequenceOf` – ranges are already sequences.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it didn't seem to work that way. Trying it again it does, so I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
struct Cube {
    let id:Int
}

...    

let array = (0..<24).compactMap {
    return Cube(id: $0)
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the use of compactMap over map, in this example?